# If evaluation not working as expected on JSP

Tags: jsp, extjs, utf-8, utf

i am facing an annoying issue with the following code

```
if (isExistAndDefined(Ext.get('checkBusyFwd')) && Ext.get('checkBusyFwd').dom.checked){
    if (hg_combo2.getValue() != hgElParms.items['voice_mail_value']
    && hg_combo2.getValue() != hgElParms.items['voice_mail_value_fr']){
        if (isEmptyValue(Ext.DomQuery.select("form[id=frm_hunt_grp]")[0].<%=VoiceGroupUtil.ATTR_HUNT_BUSY_TO_DN_NM %>.value)){
            hg_popupMsg(hgElParms.items['msg_not_empty'], hg_combo2);
            return false;
        }
        if (!checkLengthRange(Ext.DomQuery.select("form[id=frm_hunt_grp]")[0].<%=VoiceGroupUtil.ATTR_HUNT_BUSY_TO_DN_NM %>.value, 10, 15)){
            hg_popupMsg(hgElParms.items['msg_invalid_tn'], hg_combo2);
            return false;
        }
        if (!checkRegExp(Ext.DomQuery.select("form[id=frm_hunt_grp]")[0].<%=VoiceGroupUtil.ATTR_HUNT_BUSY_TO_DN_NM %>.value, /^[0-9]+$/)){
            hg_popupMsg(hgElParms.items['msg_invalid_tn'], hg_combo2);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The voice_mail_value_fr contains the french character "Boîte vocale" and voice_mail_value contains the english character "Voice mail". My problem is whenever i pass english value i.e. "Voice mail" from the drop down box the if evalueates to false **which is expected** but somehow for french value the if evaluates to true and code inside the if block get executed hindering the correct flow.

Comment: also facing one weird issue, if i remove this file from the cache and copy it again the page starts working fine. Can any one please provide some clues on what might be going wrong.

Comment: I figured out what's going wrong here, actually the value of fr coming is in utf-8 encoding but the value in jsp against which i am comparing is not. Just included the utf-8 directive as follows.

    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

When i was manually updating the cache the page automatically saves in utf-8 encoding(my guess) this may be the reason for the weird behavior i was getting.

Comment: There's no way that would fix it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess the datatype of the values here:

```
 hg_combo2.getValue() != hgElParms.items['voice_mail_value_fr']
```

They're strings, right?  In Java string evaluation is by the .equals() method.

```
!hg_combo2.getValue().equals(hgElParms.items['voice_mail_value_fr'])
```

For strings in Java, `!=` and `==` only evaluate pointer equivalence, not contents equivalence.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but may be i missed to mention that my code part is from scrptlet. You can see i am using Ext  JS libraries.I  will be more careful on explaining the question from next time. Thanks